# Custom email validation Firebase Action code

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on a Application with firebase. I want to validat a users email, but since Firebase doesn't allow to change the verification message (To help prevent spam, the message can't be edited on this email template), i can't use this. I don't want to serve English text to my users.

Is there a way to get/generate a custom ActionCode? I used this tut https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler it might solve the problem is i can get the temp actioncode somewhere.

I found applyActionCode and checkActionCode (seems the same) but not something like createActionCode

Comment: Any news on this? I don't want to write english text to my users...

Comment: This has duplicates at least [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877662/firebase-verification-email-template-editing) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381749/edit-templates-authentication-firebase)... As told in [firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714?hl=en): "For each email type, you can customize the email's sender[...] and **—for password reset emails—** the message." ... so this is something that is pretty urgent for non-English REAL projects like ours... Thanks for your offering @AlfonsoGomezJordanaManas, we are taking your advice.

Comment: but the question 'Is there a way to get/generate a custom ActionCode?' is still not answered

Answer (score 7):

### Ask for it...

Nowadays the best procedure (with just 1 step) was for us to develop an HTML file with the exact content for each of your templates (Email-Verification and Email-Change, including even the snippets %...% in the right place) and send them as attachment in the [Troubleshoot form](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) as mentioned by Alfonso in the comments of this question.

If you send the exact email HTML template file, you leave Google's people with no questions for spamming purposes other than quickly validating your HTML content and approve.

Comment: Was there an answer that was removed from this post? I don't quite understand how the troubleshoot form provides a solution to this problem. In my case I just want to edit the email verification template....

Comment: @SamStorie I'm not sure it's still the same procedure, but at the time of the answer (that's why it starts with a "Nowadays") it was done manually by Firebase's personnel. Sending the complete HTML template file with the snippets in place through the Troubleshoot form was the best procedure, so they could implement it directly with less conversation in the middle.

Answer (score 3):

you can change the language for all the templates, at the bottom...

[image: change the language for all the templates]

also you can edit manually the body and the subject for the forgot password template

Comment: but how can i do different mailtext for each languages?

Answer (score -9):

You can customize the email validation template text as you wish?  Right?

[image]