# Edit templates Authentication Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hello I start a new app with Firebase and I go to implemente Authentication method, but I need edit template for Email address verification and Change email address. This two options can't be edited, but on reset password can edit template (field: message).

The message are blocked only on options (Email address verification and Change Email address)?

I working on one app on Spanish and I really need edit this template.

[image: Email address verification]

[image: Change Password]

Comment: As it says when you hover over the question mark icon: "To help prevent spam, the message can't be edited on this email template". There is nothing we can do about that here on Stack Overflow, but if you'd like to see the functionality changes, I recommend you fill out a [Firebase feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: Thank you Frank, well maybe I need implemented alternative method for authenticate.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I understand the concept to prevent spam, but are would really good if Firebase can provide this template in another language. In my case: Spanish(es).

All my app are in Spanish and send email to verify email address in English, that's pathetic.

Comment: According to the comments, I believe this should be considered a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410923/custom-email-validation-firebase-action-code

Comment: I've already answered this in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410923/custom-email-validation-firebase-action-code/43011808#43011808), so I insist this is a duplicate and won't repeat the answer here as it is a bad-practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says when you hover over the question mark icon: "To help prevent spam, the message can't be edited on this email template". There is nothing we can do about that here on Stack Overflow, but if you'd like to see the functionality changes, I recommend you [file a Firebase feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).