# Firebase verification email template editing

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Are there or will be any way to edit the verification email template or put in different languages, not only English. The user experience is horrible for non-english users. Please, could you share the roadmap of this feature.

Thanks,
Tomás

Comment: *firebaser here* We know that allowing users to localize the email template would greatly help Firebase Authentication developers in international markets. But currently this is not possible (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410923/custom-email-validation-firebase-action-code)). will make sure your voice is added to the mix there. If you'd like to weigh in more directly, [file feature request here](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: In fact this seems to be an exact duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410923/custom-email-validation-firebase-action-code

Comment: I've already answered this in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410923/custom-email-validation-firebase-action-code/43011808#43011808), so I insist this is a duplicate and won't repeat the answer here as it is considered a bad-practice.

Comment: It would be great to have a variable in custom email handlers that would inform the language code the user had chosen.
According to this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler, currently only "mode", "oobCode", "apiKey" and "continueUrl" are available. Without a language code, we cannot fully handle all the templates and recover/reset password forms in the appropriate language.

Comment: Having a proper app, Firebase email verification is unusable simply because of a terrible email template its given. Atleast they could make 50+ templates to use or integrate somehow with mailchimp.

Answer (score 20):

Before sending firebase email you can set the language of a template. You can edit templates in different languages in firebase console (Template in English you can edit the only subject)

```js
firebase.auth().languageCode = 'ua';

firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
```

Comment: Same in Dart: 
```dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
auth.setLanguageCode("ua");
```

Comment: how do you do this in firebase admin?