# Change Forgot Password text Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm building an iOS app that uses Firebase for the database. I'm using the built-in forgot password methods supplied by the API. Is there a way to change the text in the email that is sent to the user via Firebase?

Comment: There currently is no way to change the email templates. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410923/custom-email-validation-firebase-action-code

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen You said that it is not possible to edit it. I get that you're a Firebase engineer, but I **can** edit my forgot password email template.

Comment: That sounds great. Can you tell me how?